# After updating existing cell value in .xlsx file using POI, the file is giving HTTP 403 if used by an API

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx

I have an excel file which contains many columns and one set of data row in it.
After changing the value of the **asOf** field, as I am using it in API which is taking excel file, gives 403 Forbidden error. I have checked the following things:

1. The field is updated correctly. (I checked the formatting and cell style of excel after updating it manually.)
2. If I change the cell value manually then API is giving 200.

*Image For Failure Response:* When asOf field updated by Java Code

[image]

*Image For Pass Response:* When asOf field updated manually.

[image]

*The image of field which I am updating is below:*

[image]

Below is the java code that I am using:

```
   public static void excelFileReadAndUpdate() throws IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("./src/test/resources/testdata/HoldingDataWeekendDate.xlsx"));
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("./src/test/resources/testdata/HoldingDataWeekendDate.xlsx");
    XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    XSSFRow row = sheet1.getRow(1);
    XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
    cell.setCellValue("2018-10-31");
    wb.write(fileOut);
    fileOut.close();
}
```

**Note:** I tried other approaches also like using the workbook and preserve the formatting but it is not working. If I update the field manually after opening the excel then it works.

Any suggestion/advice would be great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try to upload the manually changed file in `excelFileReadAndUpdate`. My guess: it will fail too, It looks like the authentication, session, cookies are not provided/handled correctly by the code.

Comment: @JoopEggen Hi Joop, the code that I have written is only for creating/updating the excel file after updating the field not for POSTING the file. I am posting the file through Postman which have all the configurations i.e. cookies, headers etc

Comment: `./src/test/resources/` is quite dubious for a couple of reasons. Writing also. If you do nothing in the code (comment everything out) using a manual HoldingDataWeekendDate.xlsx, that should work.

Comment: Hi Joop, actually I only wrote the piece of code that is updating and generating the excel file on ./src/test/resources/ path and then it is being used by JerseyClient for some API end-point with-in BDD API automation framework. Sorry for the confusion it created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and applying many approaches, finally, it has been resolved by applying some code giving **read/write permission** to that folder/file in java.

```
 public static void excelFileReadAndUpdate() throws IOException {

   final File file = new File("location of your excel file directory");
   file.setReadable(true, false);
   file.setExecutable(true, false);
   file.setWritable(true, false);

XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("./src/test/resources/testdata/HoldingDataWeekendDate.xlsx"));
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("./src/test/resources/testdata/HoldingDataWeekendDate.xlsx");
XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = sheet1.getRow(1);
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("2018-10-31");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
}
```